# Is the simplification of $ (\mathbf{I}s^{-1} + \mathbf{\Sigma})^{-1}$ possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My question is about the expression given by
$$ (\mathbf{I}s^{-1} + \mathbf{\Sigma})^{-1}$$ where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a covariance matrix, $s$ is a complex number, and $\mathbf{I}$ is an identity matrix.
My main problem is that is there any possible way to take the $s$ term out of the inversions or to explicitly express it in summation form. The main reason is that I am planning to take the inverse Laplace transform of the given expression.

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity help?

Comment: You can always use the geometric series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty r^n = (1 - r)^{-1},$ valid on the unit ball $\|r\| < 1$ (and $r$ in any Banach space, including the space of linear transformations).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations! But, Woodbury's identity is not working for my case. I thought that Cholezky's factorization may help then I can use the properties of triangular functions to find a solution.

Comment: @okan You could write
$$
(Is^{-1} + \Sigma)^{-1} = s(I + s \Sigma)^{-1},
$$
maybe this is helpful

Comment: Another possibility that you might find more tractable still:
$$
s(I + s\Sigma)^{-1} = s\Sigma^{-1}(sI + \Sigma^{-1})^{-1}.
$$